# Why is the alloc method not shown in the call stack?

Tags: objective-c, callstack

I am trying to understand the memory stack. I run my project and inspect how the stack changes, while moving trough the project by "step in".

I step in to something like this:

```
myClass *tmp = [[myClass alloc] init];
```

and after that I see:

```
0-[myClass init]
1-[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]
...
```

Why there is no `[myClass alloc]` between 0 and 1?
I suppose it happens because the implementation of `alloc` is closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myClass* tmp = [[myClass alloc] init];
```

is equivalent to:

```
myClass* x = [myClass alloc];
myClass* tmp = [x init];
```

So `init` operates on the result of `alloc`. In other words when `init` happens `alloc` must have already completed and returned.

Answer (score 0):

If `alloc` *called* `init`, then you could expect it to show up in the stack trace. That's how a call stack works.